# Create single object from multiple objects who got similar and NEW KEYS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
const toBeUpdated = {
  "stores": {
    "city1": [{
      "address": "13, Landiling",
      "firstName": "Robot",
      "lastName": "Tom",
      "MiddleName": "Dian"
    }]
  }
};

const updateInfo = {
  "stores": {
    "city1": [{
      "address": "13, Landiling",
      "firstName": "Robot",
      "lastName": "Tom",
      "phone": "12345678",
      "email": "test@",
      "manager": "tim"
    }]
  }
};
```

Need to update `toBeUpdated` object with the missing keys(new) and values from the updateInfo object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 spread operator for merging two objects. Try this-

```js
const toBeUpdated = {
  "stores": {
    "city1": [{
      "address": "13, Landiling",
      "firstName": "Robot",
      "lastName": "Tom",
      "MiddleName": "Dian"
    }]
  }
};

const updateInfo = {
  "stores": {
    "city1": [{
      "address": "13, Landiling",
      "firstName": "Robot",
      "lastName": "Tom",
      "phone": "12345678",
      "email": "test@",
      "manager": "tim"
    }]
  }
};

const updatedCity = toBeUpdated.stores.city1.map((city, i) => ({...city, ...updateInfo.stores.city1[i]}));

toBeUpdated.stores.city1 = updatedCity;
console.log(updatedCity);
```

Comment: Super Thanks Sajeeb

Comment: You mean nested city?

Comment: with in the city

Comment: Please explain with an example.